# Regex is matching second occurence. I need it to match first occurence

Tags: regex

This is my regex code:

```
.*(X.*)\s(.*?)\$
```

This is my data string:

```
1247.P1.06.Z01.0020N.X396X111.Y008 1247.P1.06.Z01.0020N$M234477$
```

This is properly grabbing the second item that ends with the first $ sign:

```
1247.P1.06.Z01.0020N
```

But for the first string, I want it to grab:

```
X396X111.Y008
```

Instead it is grabbing:

```
X111.Y008
```

So I want it to get the first `X` and everything up to the space.  But the second `X` is triggering the match.

The string starting with "X" is always 13 characters, so I tried specifying the length but it still started with the second X

I am fine with either pattern:

- Start with the first X and end with the space.
- Start with the first X and grab 13 characters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `.*` at the beginning of the regular expression. It's greedy, so it's skipping over the longest possible prefix that allows the rest of the regular expression to match. That forces the rest to get the last occurrence instead of the first.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WEQZAR/1)

In general, it's not necessary to put `.*` at the beginning of end of a regular expression. It just looks for the pattern anywhere in the input, so stuff around the match will just be ignored.

Comment: Thank you.  This pattern also resolved the issue:  
  
https://regex101.com/r/FcrmpV/2

Comment: That's essentially the same, since `.*?` makes it match the shortest prefix instead of the longest prefix. But it's still totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your match is too loose. A stricter regex could be:

```
X\S+\s
```

which matches an `X`, then every non whitespace character until a whitespace character.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Jl2BJS/2/

If the ID is always 13 characters you can do:

```
X.{13}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Jl2BJS/3/

Alternatively removing the `.*`, or making it non greedy with `?` or the `U` modifier would also work.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Jl2BJS/4/ or https://regex101.com/r/Jl2BJS/5/